# Regex - Non grouping and conditional block does not match

Tags: python, regex

I have this pattern:

```
>>> pat = r'(?:.*)?(name)|nombres?'
```

When I test:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('nombre', pat).group()
>>> 'nombre'
>>> re.search('name', pat).group()
>>> 'name'
```

But

```
>>> re.search('first_name', pat).group()
>>> *** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: @4castle it is just a variable, `pat` means `pattern`

Comment: @4castle fixed, that was a typo, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments in the wrong order. The pattern goes first.

Comment: _"simplest answer is always the right one"_. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As already answered the arguments are swapped it should be:

```
re.search(pat, 'first_name').group()
```

I'd say also that you may want to check if the pattern has actually matched before trying to extract the group match:

```
result = re.search(pat, 'first_name')
if result:
   print(result.group())
else:
   print("not found")
```

Comment: I do, this was a very basic example of my code. Thanks